# Tkinter module not showing output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spyder

I am trying to make a note taking list application for my school project but for some reason the note taking application isn't producing an output,i.e, a GUI (it was producing one until a month ago after which I didn't touch the project until yesterday)

I'm using the Spyder IDE and I tried updating/reinstalling but nothing worked

```
import tkinter as tk
win=tk.Tk()
win.title("Scribe")
win.geometry("800x500")
win.resizable(False,False)

from pickle import load,dump

def save():
    title = ten.get()
    con = tcon.get("1.0", tk.END)
    if title.strip() and con.strip():
        with open('notes.dat', 'rb') as fh:
            titlist=[]
            reclist=[]
            while True:
                try:
                    rec=load(fh)
                    titlist.append(rec['title'])
                    reclist.append(rec)
                except EOFError:
                    break
        if title in titlist:
            for i in reclist:
                if i['title']==title:
                    i['con']=con
        else:
            notes={}
            notes['title'] = title
            notes['con'] = con
            reclist.append(notes)
        with open('notes.dat', 'wb') as fh:
            for i in reclist:
                dump(i,fh)                
    loadlist()
    clearstuff()

def clearstuff():
    ten.delete(0, tk.END)
    tcon.delete("1.0", tk.END)

def dele():
    title = ten.get()
    if title.strip():
        found=False
        tlist=[]
        with open('notes.dat','rb') as fh:
            while True:
                try:
                    rec=load(fh)
                    if rec['title']==title:
                        found=True
                    else:
                        tlist.append(rec)
                except EOFError:
                    fh.close()
                    break
        if found==True:
            with open('notes.dat','wb') as fh:
                for i in tlist:
                    dump(i,fh)
    loadlist()
    clearstuff()

def loadlist():
    nbox.delete(0, tk.END)
    titlist=[]
    while True:
        try:
            with open('notes.dat', 'rb') as fh:
                while True:
                    try:
                        rec=load(fh)
                        titlist.append(rec['title'])
                    except EOFError:
                        break
                for i in titlist:
                    nbox.insert(tk.END, i)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return
        
def loadnote(event):
    selection = nbox.get(nbox.curselection())
    with open('notes.dat', 'rb') as fh:
        while True:
            try:
                rec=load(fh)
                if rec['title']==selection:
                    ten.delete(0, tk.END)
                    ten.insert(tk.END, selection)
                    tcon.delete("1.0", tk.END)
                    tcon.insert(tk.END, rec['con'])
            except EOFError:
                break

nfr=tk.Frame(win)
nfr.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)

nbox=tk.Listbox(nfr, width=35,height=20)
nbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
nbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", loadnote)

scroll=tk.Scrollbar(nfr,command=nbox.yview)
scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
nbox.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

cfr=tk.Frame(win)
cfr.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,padx=10,pady=10)

tlab=tk.Label(cfr,text='Title:')
tlab.pack()

ten=tk.Entry(cfr,width=100)
ten.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=5)

tlab2=tk.Label(cfr, text='Content:')
tlab2.pack()

tcon=tk.Text(cfr, width=100, height=20)
tcon.pack(pady=5)

saveb=tk.Button(cfr,text="Save",command=save)
saveb.pack(side=tk.LEFT,pady=5)

deleb=tk.Button(cfr,text="Delete",command=dele)
deleb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,pady=5)

loadlist()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Pls post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include only those parts of the code which you think causes the error. Remove everything else.

Comment: What do you mean by 'output' of your note-taking part of your app ? If I see correctly you want to save your contents in files (a csv file for the todo list and a .dat file for the notes ?)

Comment: Your question is confusingly written. But, your code **has** problematic nested loops, which caused the GUI to freeze when I ran it. You should take a glance at the `loadlist` function and remove that nested loop if this is what your question is about.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Erdit thanks for pointing that out, the loadlist function does seem to be the problem, do you have any idea how i could rectify it?

Comment: @RandomEDuck Try removing the outer while loop inside `loadlist()`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you so much, that works, could you also maybe explain why though? what's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @RandomEDuck It is because the outer while loop is not necessary.  Why do you think that it is required from the first place?